# How to fix c# compiler error, "not all code paths return a value" Word.GetLetters

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, return

Not all paths return a string value to return
I have tried to make everything return a string value but still couldn't figure it out. I have tried lots of things, but can't fix the error. I tried result.null, but still got the error. Can someone help me, I can't figure out how to fix the error, I've been working for a while trying to fix the error, but can't figure it out.

```
public letters GetLetters()
{
   var result = new letters();
   var Words = new List<string> {"start"};
   if (Words.Count == 0)
   {
      return null;
   }
   foreach (var word in Words)
   {
      if (word == null)
      {
         return null;
       }
       else
       {
          if(word.Length == 5)
          {
              string YourWord = word;
              char[] letters = YourWord.ToCharArray();
              char a = letters[0];
              char b = letters[1];
              char c = letters[2];
              char d = letters[3];
              char e = letters[4];
              result.First = a.ToString();
              result.Second = b.ToString();
              result.Third = c.ToString();
              result.Fourth = d.ToString();
              result.Fifth = e.ToString();
              return result;
            }
            else
            {
               return null;
            }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `return null;` before the final `}`. Looks like the compiler is not smart enough to figure out that if `Words.Count == 0` fails then there will always be at least one iteration of the `foreach` loop body

Comment: BTW you will need to redesign your code if you ever want to process beyond the first word in the list

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained what you are trying to accomplish with that code.

Comment: **[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)**

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to remove:

```
if (Words.Count == 0)
{
    return null;
}
```

and then *after* the loop put:

`return null;`

That way if `Words` is empty it will effectively skip the loop and then `return null;`. So no need to specifically check whether `Count` is 0. Plus you've made life easier for the compiler - it can see that every code path has a `return`.

That being said - I'd spend a little bit of time testing the code since your code ignores all except the first item in `Words`. Which is, well, weird.

*It is also odd that your `letters` type is storing characters as strings.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do but, assuming you have `Letters` class as :

```
    public class Letters
    {
        public string? First { get; set; }
        public string? Second { get; set; }
        public string? Third { get; set; }
        public string? Fourth { get; set; }
        public string? Fifth { get; set; }
    }
```

then avoid deep nesting `if/else`` statement:

```
    public static Letters GetLetters()
    {
        var result = new Letters();
        var Words = new List<string> { "start" };
        if (Words.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (var word in Words)
        {
            if (word == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (word.Length == 5)
            {
                string YourWord = word;
                char[] letters = YourWord.ToCharArray();
                char a = letters[0];
                char b = letters[1];
                char c = letters[2];
                char d = letters[3];
                char e = letters[4];
                result.First = a.ToString();
                result.Second = b.ToString();
                result.Third = c.ToString();
                result.Fourth = d.ToString();
                result.Fifth = e.ToString();

                return result;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```